# Yule Walker equations

Tags: statistics, time-series

The Yule-Walker equations relate the auto covariance of a random signal to the autoregressive (AR) model parameters. They can be used to estimate AR models from data by first estimating the auto covariance sequence for the data and then using it to solve for the autoregressive parameters.Show that the Yule-Walker equations hold even when we do not assume c=0.?

Comment: what is c? {} {

Comment: c is a constant. See Definition..  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AR_model